# how do i display search results in Python Tkinter window

Tags: python, search, button, tkinter

I am not sure if this question has been asked, but i have looked around and did not find anything specific to my problem. I am trying to build an App to search though all dirs and sub dirs for specific files by there ext(.txt, .mkv, .mp3) mostly these extention will be used (if it matters) I would like the program to display the findings in a text area(text field of sort) to show file name and path.

I have a script that i am working with but i'm not sure if it is the best way to go about it. So my question is how do i binde the existing script to the button widget. i think? there could be more. again still learning.

If there is an easier way(less steps = cleaner code) please "show me the code" Documentation is always helpful but a "hands on" method works best for me. I am still learning Python and Tkinter now. This is not the complete code. i have removed everything that was not working for me so very incomplete.

```
from tkinter import *
from tkinter import ttk
import os

Root = Tk()

def help!
for dirname, dirnames, filenames in os.walk('/'):
       for i in glob.glob(dirname+'/'+search+'*')
           print (i)
This part writen for python 2.7 now being writen in 3.x

entry = ttk.Entry(root, text = 'Enter file name')
entry.pack()

button = ttk.Button(root, text = 'Search')
button.pack()

# Text field of sort goes here!
```

Thanks in advance

UPDATE:
Complete code.
Python 3x (it should be)

```
from tkinter import *
from tkinter import ttk
from sys import argv
import glob
import os

search_input = argv
#code in question
def find_files():
    for dirname, dirnames, filenames in os.walk('/home'):
        for i in glob.glob('/*'+searchinput):
            listbox.insert(END, search_input)

#Code in question

main = Tk()
main.title("FSX")
main.geometry('640x480')

frame1 = ttk.Frame(main, height=200, width=400)
frame1.pack()

entry = Entry(frame1, width=30)
entry.pack()

button1 = ttk.Button(frame1, text="Search", command=find_files)
button1.pack()
button1.bind ('<ButtonPress>', lambda e: progressbar.start())

button2 = ttk.Button(frame1, text="Quit")
button2.pack()
button2.bind ('<ButtonPress>', lambda e: exit())

progressbar = ttk.Progressbar(frame1, orient = HORIZONTAL, length = 200,      mode = 'indeterminate')
progressbar.pack()
#progressbar.start()

frame2 = ttk.Frame(main, height=200, width=400)
frame2.pack()

listbox = Listbox(frame2, height=200, width=400)
listbox.pack(fill=BOTH, expand=YES)

progressbar.stop()

main.mainloop()
```

this is the complete code. don't mind the progress bar issue.

Comment: This is the idea. user inputs file name, then clicks button.

Comment: This is the idea. user inputs file name, then clicks button.
When button is clicked, program searches for user input.
Whatever files are found, display in Label/Text field.
At this point:
1. Display's all files and folder starting from / Even though i've *.txt. (odd)

2. When i click button it displays in terminal window not text/label area?? (How do i fix?)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I modified your example to show the found files in a [listbox](http://effbot.org/tkinterbook/listbox.htm). In this example I use for log files in /tmp folder. The found files are saved in `found_files` list and then displayed in listbox.

```
from tkinter import *
from tkinter import ttk
import glob
import os

search = '*log'


found_files = []

for dirname, dirnames, filenames in os.walk('/tmp'):
    for i in glob.glob(dirname+'/'+search+'*'):
        print(i)
        found_files.append(i)



root = Tk()
root.geometry( "640x480" );


listbox = Listbox(root)

for a_file in found_files:
    listbox.insert(END, a_file)

listbox.pack(fill=BOTH, expand=YES)

root.mainloop()
```

[image]

Comment: Thoughts on how to do this when user clicks the search button?

Comment: It seems as a new question. If so, you can make new one.

Answer (score 0):

```
labl = Label(text="{}".format(Result goes here))
labl.pack()
```

You could display your result like this one. Check for `pack()` parameters to design your label. What we do here is simple, `text` parameter of `Label` function is taking a specific data with `format()` function.

If your result is from a function, then you have to put it in your function. For example;

```
def fnk():
    a=range(1,100)
    lst1=[]
    for t in range(6):
        while len(lst1)<6:
            x=random.choice(a)
            if str(x) not in lst1:
                lst1.append(str(x))
    labl = Label(text="{}".format(" ".join(lst1)), fg="red",font="Times 35 bold")
    labl.pack()

bttn = Button(text="Start", command = fnk)
bttn.pack(side=LEFT)
```

Like a program like this, whenever you click to `Start` button, you will see different six numbers on your screen in range(1,100). Better you put your results in a list, and put them in `format()` example above.